# Restore Iptable Rules on Ubuntu20

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Last night I was trying to undo some ip table changes I did and I ended up doing iptables -F,
Is there anyway to get back to normal? I'm on an ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

After you flushed all rules, this is your new "normal"...

If you have installed `iptables-persistent` you might be able to restore the last saved state with `iptables-restore /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

Otherwise you have to "restore" the rules by typing them in again.

Comment: What are the basic rules in order to allow me to be able to access my server again?

Comment: Set the default to "accept" with `iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT`, then insert your rules and as LAST rule you should drop evrything else: `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP`

Comment: @Virsacer I think if the policies or INPUT or OUTPUT were DROP, OP cut its own remote access, but forgot to mention it in the question but only in last comment:  "be able to access my server again". So it's all about out of band remote access: remote console, remote reboot etc.

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete IPtables rules, you cannot get them back.

Run these commands to delete all IPtables rules:

```
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t filter -X
```

-t is the flag for the table, there are 4 tables in IPtables. -F flushes the specified table. -X deletes all chains except the defaults in a given table.